# Android: save downloaded data using DownloadManager in the internal memory

Tags: android, memory, internal, download-manager

I am downloading data from a server using the `DownloadManager` class in Android. I want to save data in the internal memroy (data/data/mypackage/files/...) instead of the external memory. How to do this?

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) DownloadApplicationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(MY_LINK));
    req.setTitle(MY_TITLE)
                    .setDescription("Downloading ....")
                    // download the package to the /sdcard/downlaod path.
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                            MY_PATH);
            long enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);
```

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6494627/181714)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
// if there is no SD card
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
            directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
            photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");

            // if no directory exists, create new directory
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

            // if phone DOES have sd card
        } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
            // search for directory on SD card
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
            photoDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");

            // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
            // results
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @BlaineOmega: how to use this code? setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(directory, "bla.ext") or something?

Comment: No, it is just code within a method. If you want to create a method called `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` you could, you would just put my code inside the method.