# Android: Cannnot save data downladed from server using DownloadManager to internal memory

Tags: android, memory, android-contentprovider, internal, download-manager

I am downloading data from server using the DownloadManager class in android. Data are saves to the external memory. But I want to save them to the internal memory. I did my researches and what I've found is from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494627/download-to-internal-memory-possible). I tried the second solution of *cyngus* :

```
public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.provider.Downloads";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME + "/downloads")

DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(LINK));
req.setDestinationUri(CONTENT_URI);
```

It didnt work, it gave me the error:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: content://com.provider.Downloads/downloads`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [doc for `DownloadManager.Request`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri%28android.net.Uri%29) clearly mentions that the destination you set for any of the `setDestination*` methods must be on external storage and that your app must have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:

> Set the local destination for the downloaded file. Must be a file URI to a path on external storage, and the calling application must have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

I don't see how it would be possible to provide path to internal storage here.

Comment: mmmm ok, but according to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494627/download-to-internal-memory-possible how can DownloadManager write to a content provider?

Comment: I don't think that will work either. The `DownloadManager.Request` works with _file paths_ and not with `ContentProvider`s. If you look at the source code for `DownloadManager` you'll see that ultimately the path that you set in setDestination* is treated as a file path.

Comment: mm ok, Thank you! So I have to save data to the external memory or to use another class than DownlaodManager.