# Android Download Manager store location

Tags: android, service, download

I want to download some files into the internal storage of an app.

I would like to use the Download Manager as it takes care of network and other stuff.

Where does it stores the files?

Are they stored in internal memory or external?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494627/download-to-internal-memory-possible

Answer (score 0):

You can set destination like

```
     request.setDestinationUri(yourDownloadfileUri);
```

But be aware Download manager has many [well known bugs](http://www.hafizpariabi.com/2013/05/workaround-bug-in-androids.html). I hardly advice you to implement your own download procedure. You will save time and effort. DownloadManager is IMO unpredictable and i have spend quite few hours fixing it. Dont want to use it again